Integrate LINE authentication in ios app using cordova
I want to integrate LINE authentication in my ios app which is build using cordova. I followed the actual documentation on LINE sdk page but no success.
can anyone tell me exact steps I need to follow in order to authenticate using LINE auth and grab the token.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
